# TCL calling proc that is in another file, but the proc is not found: invalid command

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I am new to TCL.  I excute TCL code via: "`tclsh85 FOD/Scripts/program1.tcl`" from DOS window under Windows Vista.

`program1.tcl` included a "`set junk [tproc $a]`" and this give "`invalid command name tproc`".

`tproc` is defined in `program2.tcl` which is in directory "`c:a/b/lib`".  What do I need to do to have TCL find the proc when I run  "`tclsh85 FOD/Scripts/program1.tcl`"?

Answer (score 3):

Did you `source` program2.tcl in program1.tcl ?

If not then you need to `source "program2.tcl"` before calling `tproc`

See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/source.htm

You should also familiar yourself with the Tcl `package` command at http://wiki.tcl.tk/9859

Comment: Note to @user1985580, the `source` command will essentially execute program2.tcl within the current program. If program2 does more stuff that just define the procedure, you should extract the procedure into its own file and your program and program2 should both source that new file. That is the essence of creating a Tcl package.